# Tree, no uncountable antichains

Tags: set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

Show that if a $\omega_1$ tree (that is, each vertex has height less than $\omega_1$ and each level $\alpha < \omega_1$ is countable and non-empty) has no uncountable anti chains, and in addition each vertex has at least two immediate successors, then the tree has no uncountable chain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: If there’s an uncountable chain, there’s a branch through $T$. Look at the $x$’s in the picture below:

```
         o  
         |\  
         o x  
         |\  
         o x  
         |\  
         o x  
         |\  
         o x  
          .  
          .  
          .
```

(Note that you don’t need the assumption that the levels are countable.)

Comment: Strange, in set theory trees are growing up! :-)

Comment: What do you mean, "there's a branch throught T"?

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat: A chain that has a node on each level.

Comment: In the picture the x's do not form a chain

Comment: @Asaf: I speak of height, rather than depth, but I’ve always drawn them growing down, partly because it’s easier, and partly because that’s the way the Ken Kunen and others at Madison drew them.

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat: Of course not; the $o$’s do. The $x$’s form ... ?

Comment: Thanks, I got it. Such a simple question once you look at a drawing :/

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Prove by contrapositive. Suppose there was an uncountable chain. Use the fact that each point in the chain has at least two successors and construct an antichain.

Remember that if $x<y$ in the chain, and $x_1$ and $y_1$ are successors of $x,y$ which are not in the chain then $x_1\nless y_1$, otherwise the order is not a tree.